# Tensorflow object detection API tfrecord

Tags: tfrecord

Im new to the tensorflow TFRecord. so Im studying Tensorflow object detection API codes

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md

but I can`t find the codes that load tfrecord.
I think they use .config file to load tfrecord because I found this in config file.

```
tf_record_input_reader {  
input_path: "/path/to/train_dataset.record-?????-of-00010" 
}
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: i believe that is referring to the config file, you can get the sample config files with the same entry here

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs

Answer (score 0):

Have you converted your dataset to TFRecord format yet?
If so, you should have a path which contains your training dataset sharded to a few record files, with the format 
`<path_to_training_data>/<train_dataset>.record-?????-of-xxxxx`

Where `<path_to_training_data>` is the abovementioned path to your training dataset, `<train_dataset>` is the file name you gave to each file, `xxxxx` is the number of record files created (e.g. 00010), and `?????` should be left as is, and is used as a format to all record files.
Once you've replaced `<path_to_training_data>`, `<train_dataset>` and `xxxxx` to the correct values of your dataset, TF OD API should handle everything else (finding all records, reading them, etc.).

Note there's usually tf_record_input_reader for both training dataset and eval dataset (validation/test), and each should have the corresponding above-mentioned values (path, dataset name, number of files).